# Chrome: Failed to load resource?

Tags: google-chrome, cross-browser

http://catalog.openletterbooks.org/authors/20-winterbach

I'm using google's shopping cart on this page, which had been working perfectly, until recently, on all browsers. Now, the cart doesn't work on Chrome--when you click the Add to Cart button nothing happens. It appears that the page isn't fully loading, and therefore the javascript isn't getting applied (it should apply onload is my understanding).

In developer tools, the only error I see is 'Failed to load resource'. No amount of googling has been able to give me an answer as to what that error might indicate in my case.

When I run an Audit, it won't complete the Audit because it can't finish loading the page.

The site uses Rails, if that means anything. And it's on Dreamhost.

I should also mention: if I run the application locally and access it with Chrome, the page works perfectly again. This suggested to me that the problem might be something with the server, but I haven't been able to figure out exactly where to begin looking.

Anyone have any suggestions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There are two things to check. First, upgrade to the latest version of Chrome. Then use the Network panel to check if the DOMContentLoaded (the blue vertical line crossing the entire view) fires for your page (for this, you need to reload your page with this panel being active). I believe the latest Chromes will show which resource actually fails to load.